# Using Layouts in CompositeView in Marionette.js?

Tags: marionette

I currently use a CompositeView to display numerous ItemViews, each representing a comment. Now, I want to be able to reply to a comment: when the user selects a "reply" button (part of the ItemView), I want to show a form right underneath the comment for the user to reply in.

My idea was to use a Layout for this, containing two regions: one for the comment (as currently represented by the ItemView) and one for the reply form (the latter being only shown after the user clicks the "reply" button).

Is it possible to specify a Layout as the itemView-property of a CompositeView and render the original ItemView (representing, in my case, a comment) within this Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout extends ItemView adding support for regions, so that should work fine.  When you handle the 'reply' event, display your commenting view in your (previously empty) comments region.

Comment: john is correct. you can specify any object that extends from Backbone.View as a CompositeView's `itemView` attribute. This includes all Marionette views, and any other view type from any other Backbone library.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still not succeeding, though. I specified a layout having two regions, namely 'commentRegion' and 'replyFormRegion'. I defined this layout to be the CompositeView's itemView. When showing the CompositeView, the Layout's template is displayed (as many times as there are model instances in the CompositeView's collection). So far so good. Now, when the Layout initializes, I want to show the original comment ItemView in the Layout's 'commentRegion'. How can I achieve this? Maybe using this.commentRegion.show() in initialize? What to pass to show() to show the model?

Comment: I guess its about passing the model instance from the layout to the view. I thus mark this question solved.